# Web audio api support in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, html, web-audio-api

I'm totally new to Web Audio Api and I need to know some info about it.

What should I install to Eclipse 3.6 to support web audio api?

With web audio api, can I send a frequency in Hz and a sound pressure in decibel and hear the sound that these variables make?

Is HTML 5 necessary for web audio api?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if there's a Web Audio API module in Eclipse yet.

With the web audio api, you can create an oscillator with a given waveform, and vary the frequency (in Hertz) and the gain - however, gain is not set in decibels, as we can't control absolute sound pressure levels in your environment.  Gain is a unitless measure (1 is unity).

You will need an HTML5 browser that supports the Web Audio API, such as Chrome, Safari or recent nightly builds of Firefox.